# PHP Warning mySql_connect() Access denied for user 'a34525_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on line 4

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I have this error when I send my HTML formular here's the code

```
<?php

include ("config.php"); 
mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("error1".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("error2".mysql_error());
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `cartago_basedepruebas`.`USUARIOS` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`, `ESTADO`,`PASSWORD`) VALUES ('$_POST[NOMBRE]', '$_POST[EMAIL]', '$_POST[URL]', '$_POST[ESTADO]','$_POST[PASSWORD]) ");

?>
```

and on the config.php

```
<?php
$server = localhost;
$database ="'a34525_nombres";
$db_user ="'a34525_user";
$db_pass ="onetwothree";
?>
```

any ideas?

Comment: 1. you do not have access to your database, 2. don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` calls. Switch to MySQLi or PDO, 3. read about SQL injection and prepared statements

Comment: 4. add some error handling

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a extra simple quote on $database and $db_user?

Check it.

Comment: Try with this: `<?php
$server = localhost;
$database ="a34525_nombres";
$db_user ="a34525_user";
$db_pass ="onetwothree";
?>`

Comment: Can you enter to the database by phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes I can. I fixed another error of my code but anyways It's still wrong and giving me the same error